# Correct Monitors Not Detected on 16.04 Nvidia or Nouveau

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, xorg, monitor

Upon installation of 16.04, a Dell 2408WFP was not detected by the default Nouveau driver.  I then installed the actual Nvidia driver hoping for a different result, but that yielded the same result.

I've now changed monitors again, and it is still not showing up.  These monitors only show up as `CRT-0` in the `NVIDIA X Server Settings` control panel.

Any ideas as to what I can do to force X and the Nvidia drivers to detect the proper monitor that's attached?

[Here's a copy](https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/fec83523a02fe1a500c10fcb1d621348) of my Xorg.0.log for review.

When I modify `xorg.conf` with the following:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes "1366x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I unfortunately get the following error:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 634
CRTC 634: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 634: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 634: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 634: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 635
CRTC 635: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 635: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 635: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 635: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 636
CRTC 636: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 636: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 636: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 636: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 637
CRTC 637: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 637: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 637: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 637: trying mode 320x240@120Hz with output at 1152x864@60Hz (pass 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by manually setting up my own `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "x183h"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    ModeLine       "1366x768_60_0" 85.9 1366 1438 1626 1798 768 769 772 795 +hsync +vsync
    Option         "IgnoreEDID" "True"
    Option         "UseEDID" "FALSE"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "ModeValidation"  "NoWidthAlignmentCheck, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck"
    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "TRUE"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1366x768_60_0"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```